# It keeps saying: TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a turtle/text based RPG (basically its a computerized d&d dungeonmaster) in python to impress my friends, my classmates and my teacher for my computing GCSE and my code seems alright; It draws out the room, enemies and any other things fine, has the text input printed in python shell. This is what it says:

```
File "E:\GCSE's\RPG No.1 Test code..py", line 22, 
in chest contents+=list.append(chosen_loot)
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

But this is the code segment that it's on about:

```
def chest():
    contents=[]
    chosen_loot=[]
    for n in range(2):
        loot=["Chestplate", "Vambraces", "Chausses", "Sabaton", "Zweihänder"]
        chosen_loot+=random.choice(loot)
        contents+=list.append(chosen_loot)
```

Please help! I've been up since 10:00 at night working on this thing!

Comment: Do you mean `contents.append(chosen_loot)`?

Comment: Oh, right, well, I'm now kind of embarrassed, especially because that worked....

Comment: When the documentation says *list*`.append()`, it means that you call `append()` on a list object.  += and append have (more or less)  the same effect, use one or the other, not both (generally append is preferred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is completely wrong. First, `chosen_loot+=random.choice(loot)` adds a `list` and a string, which doesn't ordinarily work except with that augmented assignment (`+=`), which extends the `list` to include each character as a separate item.

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a+= 'abc'
>>> a
[1, 2, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

That line should be `chosen_loot = random.choice(loot)`. You didn't even need two `list`s, so I don't know what was going on there.

Next, `contents+=list.append(chosen_loot)` isn't right at all. First, you're doing `list.append`, which could work if you called it properly, with the reference to the `list` you're interested in (`contents` in this case), but generally you want to do something like `contents.append(chosen_loot)`. Next, you're concatenating with `+=` on top of that. You've got several potentially useful bits of code, but you can't just mush them together and expect them to work. That line should just be `contents.append(chosen_loot)`.

Next, you're trying to get two random items from a `list`. The way to do that is with `random.sample`.

```
contents = random.sample(loot, 2)
```

Finally, even that doesn't do anything, because it all gets thrown away when the function ends. You need to return something:

```
def chest():
    return random.sample(["Chestplate",
                          "Vambraces",
                          "Chausses",
                          "Sabaton",
                          "Zweihänder"], 2)
```

That will produce two random items.

Comment: If I'm honest, with the random functions, I barely know what I'm doing. It hasn't even been mentioned in my GCSE Computing class yet and we only just finished a term-long project in which half of us actually, independently coded 3 basic games, nowhere near what I'm trying, the other half of the class just stole the work off the others and made it look like their own. So for a kid doing his GCSE's and bearing in mind, I only found out about the random module yesterday and if it wasn't for my mates I'd be flunking that class